# Where to define PAINTSTRUCT and why to define HDC?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, gdi

My questions are very simple and not very important.

1. I began to learn writing Win32 applications. When I read code from other people, I often see that they put `PAINTSTRUCT ps;` before the switch statement in `WndProc`. Why don't they put this into the case `WM_PAINT`? They allocate memory for `ps` and then don't use it?
2. I always see `PAINTSTRUCT ps; HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);`. But I checked the value of `ps.hdc` multiple times and the values of `ps.hdc` and `hdc` are equal everytime. Is there another reason for defining `hdc` than just readability or writing less code?

(And sorry, if my English is bad and the questions aren't at the level of this community)

Comment: They usually just make it static inside the WndProc so it is only allocated once and not every time the switch statement is called. Also since HDC is a pointer type, it causes a drop through case statement if declared within the case statement and so it is usually also defined within the WndProc rather than the switch statement. Otherwise your case statement will need brackets. Other than that, it's just readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer Point 1: The Win32 API was designed for C (it is quite old) and to put the `PAINTSTRUCT ps;` inside the `case` statement would require putting the contents of the `case` inside braces `{}` as C doesn't allow for inline declarations. C++ may also have a problem declaring variables inside `case` statements without the braces - calling destructors without calling the constructor. You will quickly find that the `switch() case...` style will become awkward to maintain, the function will become quite large and unwieldy and it doesn't play well with things like Intellisense. Quite often, you'll see developers use a map to associate functions with specific messages:-

```
WindowProc (args)
{
  func_ptr = some_map.GetValue (message_type)
  if func_ptr not null
    call func_ptr
  else
    DefWindowProc (args)
}
```

As for Point 2, the value of `hdc` will be `null` when there's an error and it's looks cleaner to use `hdc` instead of `ps.hdc`. Also, an `hdc` is easier to pass to other functions than a `ps`. But apart from that, the documentation doesn't call out any reason why `ps.hdc` would be different to the result of `BeginPaint`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I learned a lot about how to design my code right, when I make Win32 applications. The little details haven't yet been mentioned in the book I read currently.

Answer (score 2):

> When I read code from other people, I often see that they put PAINTSTRUCT ps; before the switch statement in WndProc. Why don't they put this into the case WM_PAINT?

Several possibilities:

1. They are or were using an older style of C where all local variables have to be defined at the beginning of a function.
2. Depending on your compiler and its warning level, you can get warnings when trying to declare variables inside cases in a switch statement.
3. They're just being sloppy.

A window procedure probably shouldn't "handle" the messages but instead dispatch them to message-specific handlers.  Thus the WM_PAINT case in the WndProc should probably call a separate function that does the painting, and the PAINTSTRUCT could be local to that separate function.  But we're venturing into opinion, so I'll leave it at that.

> I always see `PAINTSTRUCT ps; HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);`.

I seem to recall there was an obscure case where the returned device context handle could be different than the one in the PAINTSTRUCT, but was probably extremely rare and may not exist in modern versions of Windows.

Consider the returned HDC a convenience.  If your painting is simple and doesn't need any of the other fields in the PAINTSTRUCT, this gives you an easy way to refer to the device context.

Answer (score 1):

1. It really makes no difference, and many implementations will "allocate" the memory every time the window procedure is called whether the variables are declared at the top of the function or within the `WM_PAINT` case of the switch.
2. [BeginPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does more than simply return `ps.hdc`.

Comment: 1. It does make a difference. Declaring variables with too wide a scope makes code less readable and makes it easier to make mistakes. 2. You missed the point completely. The question is why a local `hdc` would be declared rather than using `ps.hdc`.

Comment: I know that `BeginPaint` does more than simply return `ps.hdc`. But, if`hdc`and `ps.hdc` are equal, I don't have to store the return value of `BeginPaint` in a variable, because all values I need already exist in `ps`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree with your point 2 (although the question cannot be considered entirely clear on that point), but regarding point 1 it is you who have "missed the point entirely" since his question seemed to be about "allocation", not "readability". Of course it's best to define separate functions for each event. Who would disagree with that?

Comment: @ooga OK, the asker asked about allocation. But that won't matter. What will a single paint struct on the stack cost?

Answer (score 1):

> I often see that they put `PAINTSTRUCT ps;` before the switch statement in `WndProc`. Why don't they put this into the case `WM_PAINT`? They allocate memory for ps and then don't use it?

It's bad practice to do so. Best practice is to call a separate function to do the painting and avoid having a window procedure that is pages long. But if you have to paint in the window procedure, declare your variables with as local a scope as possible.

> Is there another reason for defining hdc than just readability or writing less code?

It's a convenience. Since a paint function refers again and again to the device context, it is convenient to store it in a local variable and so make the code less verbose. And yes, when `BeginPaint` succeeds, it is guaranteed that the `HDC` returned by `BeginPaint` is equal to the `HDC` in the paint struct.